# Installing myeclipse on mac os x10.9

Tags: macos, myeclipse

I am not able to install myeclipse.
Error is it is not able to open(no mountable file system).
WHAT is the problem?
What should i do(new to mac)

Comment: What can't you open? Is it the DMG file or the installer in the DMG? Sounds like the DMG, in which case, you might have a corrupt download, so you could try downloading again. Which release are you trying to install?

Comment: What is Dmg? i think Installer is not opening the error i mention was coming.i installed it from the official website only. Can u please provide the link.

Comment: The download is a dmg file, which is a kind of disk image. Double clicking that brings up a Finder window with the contained files displayed, including the actual installer executable. The download site is https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/download/ When you mention the "official site" what is the link?